# Access $scope from isolated directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to change a $scope variable from inside an isolated directive, how is this possible?

I have tried using the '@, =, &' syntax in the directive scope but cannot get it to work.

This is my simplified code

JS

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.hello = 'hello';
}

app.directive('testDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>{{text}}</div>',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.text = 'this is my text';
            scope.hello = 'hello world!';
        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
    {{ hello }}
    <test-directive />
</body>
```

This is the output i want

```
hello world!
this is my text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `require` option on the directive and specify a parent controller. This will pass the controller to your link function as the last argument:

```
app.directive('testDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>{{text}}</div>',
        require: '^testCtrl',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, testCtrl) {
            scope.text = 'this is my text';
            testCtrl.setHello('hello world!');
        }
    };
});
```

Note you have to create this `testCtrl.setHello()` method on your controller. This is because you get the controller itself, not its injected scope:

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.hello = 'hello';
    this.setHello = function(newHello) {
      $scope.hello = newHello;
    }
}
```

Also, if you don't really care about strictly enforcing the controller dependency, you can directly access `scope.$parent.$parent.hello` from your directive.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, the directive must be in snake-case:

```
<test-directive />
```

In your script, the directive must be defined in camel case:

```
app.directive('testDirective', function() {
});
```

Also, add the ngController directive:

```
<body ng-controller="testCtrl>
</body>
```

Comment: Edited that, didn't help to the solution tho.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of the isolated scope and modifying the parent scope

Answer (score 0):

Here's what was missing:

1. ng-controller was not defined
2. @ means passing the attribute as a string, = means binding the property to a property from the parent's scope (which is what we need here) and & means passing in a function from the parents scope to be called later.
3. when the directive is called "testDirective" it looks in the HTML as follows:`<test-directive></test-directive>` as camel cases in JS need to be
   seperated by "-" in HTML.

`<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
    {{ hello }}
    <test-directive hello-from-parent="hello"></test-directive>
</body>`

`app.directive('testDirective', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        hello: "=helloFromParent"
      },
      template: '<div>{{text}}</div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.text = 'this is my text';
        scope.hello = 'hello world';
      }
  }
});`

I set up a working [plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wqlNQ2M7mMfX54rlpsgb?p=preview)